# describe odd number series

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, number-theory, numerical-methods

How to solve

odd's

1 - > 1

3 - > 2

5 - > 4

7 - > 5

9 - > 7

11 - > 8

13 - > 10

15 - > 11

17 - > 13

19 - > 14

21 - > 16

23 - > 17

25 - > 19

27 - > 20

.........

.........

.........

**127 - > ?**

---

odd's

1 - > 1

3 - > 2

```
   ----> 3
```

5 - > 4

7 - > 5

```
  -----> 6
```

9 - > 7

11 - > 8

13 - > 10

15 - > 11

17 - > 13

19 - > 14

21 - > 16

23 - > 17

25 - > 19

27 - > 20

.........

.........

.........

**127 - > ?**

like

**527 - > ?**

**53467 - > ?**

**2345637 - > ?**

**4563423597 - > ?**

explain this odd number series

any good math formula

if a odd number is 34567 - > (?) then how to get this number sequence (?)

Comment: What do odds have to do with anything??  You're describing a sequence.

Comment: $a_n=\frac{-(n\bmod8)^3+12(n\bmod8)^2-23(n\bmod8)+36}{24} + 6\cdot\left\lfloor\frac{n}{8}\right\rfloor$

Comment: The sequence jumps by $1$ and $2$ alternatively hence its $n$th term (the image of $2n-1$) is $$n-1+\left\lceil\frac{n}2\right\rceil.$$ For example, $$4563423597=2\cdot2281711799-1\to2281711799-1+1140855900=3422567698.$$

Comment: So to answer your question: $a_{127}=95$, $a_{527}=395$, $a_{53467}=40100$, $a_{2345637}=1759228$, $a_{4563423597}=3422567698$.

Comment: @Prabur Those hints may all be too advanced. Which numbers are present on the LHS. Correct, the odd numbers. Now which numbers are *missing* from the RHS? Yes, 3,6. What are the next three that are missing? So what is the pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that:

$f(n)=
 \cases
 {
  1+3\lfloor{n/4}\rfloor&$n\equiv1\pmod4$\\
  2+3\lfloor{n/4}\rfloor&$n\equiv3\pmod4$\\
 }
$

---

Or simply:

$f(n)=(n\bmod4+1)/2+3\lfloor{n/4}\rfloor$

---

Which gives:

- $f(127)=95$
- $f(527)=395$
- $f(53467)=40100$
- $f(2345637)=1759228$
- $f(4563423597)=3422567698$

Answer (score 1):

We can obtain the sequence this way: if $n$ is odd, then we define $f(n)=\min\{n/4-\left[n/4\right],\left[n/4\right]+1-n/4\},$ i.e. $g(n)=n/4\pm f(n)$ is the closest integer to $n/4.$ Then the sequence is $n-g(n).$
Or, if put in a more elementary way, just notice that for an odd $n,$ the sequence $a_n$ is $\begin{cases}6m\pm1,&n=8m\pm1\\
6m\pm4,&n=8m\pm3\end{cases}.$
Since $127=8\times16-1,$ we have $a_n=95.$ Similarly you can answer other questions.

Hope this helps.

---

**Edit:**
As in the comment of @almagest: the most straightforward way to see the pattern is to notice that the first missed numbers are $3,6,9,\cdots,$ so the pattern is clear.

Comment: I don't understand this. Your min will always be $n/4-[n/4]$. Is that what you intended?

Comment: But I don't understand: The square bracket means the Gaussian function, the biggest integer less than or equal to the argument. I don't see why the minimum is always the first.

Comment: It would be more helpful to anyone looking at this in the future to incorporate the substance of my comment under the question in your answer. Don't bother to attribute it to me. Let's try and clean this up a little! :) On the [ ] you have min of k and k+ 1, the first has to be smaller whatever k is.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know what I was thinking. And I added some simple clarification; tell me if further modifications are needed. :)